# In a list, it is possible to obtain the object type of an object based on a object property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a list of different object

```js
const list : MyListItem[] = [
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label',
         type: 'text'                                                     
    },
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label2',
         type: 'textarea'                                                     
    },
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label3',
         type: 'checkbox',
         label: 'checkbox label'                                                     
    }                                                
]
```

```js
interface MyListItem {
    size: number,
    name: string,
    type: 'text'| 'textarea' | 'checkbox'   
}
```

```js
interface MyListItemCheckbox {
    size: number,
    name: string,
    type: 'text'| 'textarea' | 'checkbox' ,
    label: string  
}
```

It is possible to get the inner object interface based on the type item ?

When the type is `checkbox` I would like to get `MyListItemCheckbox` othewise `MyListItem`.

> (my real case is a bit more complex, the example above is made to semplify the explanation)

Comment: I guess you have to use a `(MyListItem | MyListItemCheckbox )[]` type for the list and then use type narrowing to get the concrete thing `if ("label" in item)  { /* item is MyListItemCheckbox */ } /* item is MyListItem  */`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use what is called a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions). Basically, the `list` should be assigned to a type that is a union of two interfaces: one that contains the `label` property, and one that doesn't.

An example is below (also [check it out on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ckg+LqNLSGdYEro6INbrWtXjIVLY4bY7Xb3qNTHX7g4A8gBpCcPiAA)):

```js
const list : MyListItem[] = [
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label',
         type: 'text'
    },
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label2',
         type: 'textarea'
    },
    {
         size: 100,
         name: 'label3',
         type: 'checkbox',
         label: 'checkbox label'                                                     
    }                                                
]

interface BaseListItem {
    size: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;
}

interface TextLikeListItem extends BaseListItem {
    type: 'text'| 'textarea';
}

interface CheckboxListItem  extends BaseListItem {
    type: 'checkbox';
    label: string;
}

type MyListItem = TextLikeListItem | CheckboxListItem;

for (let item of list) {
  if (item.type === 'text' || item.type === 'textarea') {
    console.log(item);       // `item` is inferred as TextLikeListItem
    console.log(item.label); // Error
  } else if (item.type === 'checkbox') {
    console.log(item);       // `item` is inferred as CheckboxListItem
    console.log(item.label); // OK
  }
}
```

Comment: Also adding `type guards` to determine the type of `ListItem` would be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to extend your interface. For example:

```
interface MyListItem {
    size: number;
    name: string;
}

interface MyTextListItem extends MyListItem {
    type: 'text' | 'textarea';
    placeholder: string;
}

interface MyCheckboxListItem extends MyListItem {
    type: 'checkbox';
    checked: boolean;
}

type Item = MyTextListItem | MyCheckboxListItem;

const text: Item = {
  size: 2,
  name: '',
  type: 'text',
  placeholder: 'a'
}

const checkbox: Item = {
  size: 2,
  name: '',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: true
}
```

Is that what you want? Now the typings are correct. Here you can see it in [action](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-v6pyrrpzwy?file=/src/index.tsx:0-693)